# ¿Cómo obtener el color de una casilla de un tablero de ajedrez en Python?

Tags: python

Muy buen día a todos! Esperando que se encuentren muy bien, en un curso que estoy tomando de estadística descriptiva con R y con Python, me pusieron el siguiente problema:

> Busca la imagen de un tablero de ajedrez en Google y fíjate en la nomenclatura de las casillas. Escribe una secuencia que lea una letra y un número de teclado correspondiente a una casilla de un tablero de ajedrez y que indique si esta casilla es negra o blanca.

Les agradecería mucho su orientación, la verdad estoy iniciando en este mundo de la programación, y me entusiasma mucho, solo que a veces me atoro.

Lo que se me había ocurrido hacer era nombrar a cada casilla de acuerdo a su nomenclatura, y hacer que cada casilla fuera una variable que guardara como valor un string que diga el color de la casilla en cuestión:

```
  a1 = "Negro"
```

Después de hacer eso con cada una de las casillas que conforman al tablero, mi intención era generar una serie de instrucciones que permitieran introducir la nomenclatura de la casilla y que al introducirlo arrojará como resultado el valor de la variable en cuestión.

Ese fue mi razonmiento inicial, si estoy mal, de antemano pido una disculpa.

Comment: Pues, depende de los requerimientos que te pongan al plantear el problema. Lo que estás diciendo que quieres hacer y no has hecho porque no hay código, lo puedes probar y ver si cumple con lo que te pide el curso. Luego,si tienes lío con eso, traes el lío específico y lo miramos entre todos

Comment: Hint: Las filas están numeradas de 1 a 8, las columnas de "a" hasta "h". Transforma la columna a entero de 1 a 8 (columna "a" queda columna 1). Suma la fila y la columna. Si es par, es blanco. Si es impar, es negro.

Comment: no uses 64 variables.. usa una matriz ;) o mejor lo que dijo Candid...